# deno oak - crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, paypal, deno

I get this error in deno oak when i  want to reach a page of my website. it occured since ive tried to integrate the Paypal SDK js module. I've tried to do an npm install because i forgot that deno doesn't support npm natively.

However, i choose the method where i have to add a script in my html file. Then i launched my app, and gone to  my webpage. it throwed me an error : crbug/1173575. I saw that there is a ton of questions about this error, but i tried many solutions and it doesn't resolve anything. Since that, even if i deleted this added code, it continues to throw me this error ...

Comment: Your question seams to be very specific and will probably make sense only to people in a similar situation. Just a word of advice: Even thought we developers love to write all small letters, I would suggest that you take a moment and make your texts more grammatically correct. I can only recommend a Chrome extension like LanguageTool. Keep on learning. ;-)

Comment: thanks for this advice   but not so much mistakes of my little "storytelling " in your recommended extension, i think that finding people in a similar situation is the purpose of this forum @Draško Kokić , but anyway i edited a little bit my text, and language tool looks really cool